# Divshot CSS import not working

Tags: css, divshot

After upgrading to the release version of Divshot, I've noticed that CSS `@import` rules aren't being loaded in the preview panel.

For example:

```
 @import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.1.1/css/font-awesome.min.css");
 @import url("styles.css");
```

does nothing.

I have tried different syntax and it didn't seem to help.  I can put them in the head of the HTML page instead of calling them in a CSS file, but that only works for straight CSS. Font Awesome and Google font libraries rely on `@import` rules to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Divshot runs everything secured via SSL, you will need to use the `https` versions of any CSS imports, or use `//` to make it work both ways.